# How can I specifiy a generic collection as restriction in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Aloha

I have a method with (pseudo) signature:

```
public static T Parse<T>(string datadictionary) where T : List<U>
```

This doesn't build. How can I restrict the  in the method to accept only generic List<> objects (which should of cource not contain T's but something else :)

I need to restrict the type of T because I need to call a method on it in this code. The type passed in is a custom collection (based on List).

```
public class MyCollection<T> : List<T> where T: MyClass, new()
{
    public void Foo();
}


public static T Parse<T>(string datadictionary) where T : MyCollection<U>
{
    T.Foo();
}
```

-Edoode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can have two type parameters:

```
public static T Parse<T, U>(string datadictionary) where T : List<U>
```

That way you'll also actually know what U is (in a compile-time manner)...

EDIT: Alternatively (and better), just specify the element type and change the return type:

```
public static List<T> Parse<T>(string datadictionary)
```

e.g.

```
List<int> data = Parse<int>(whatever);
```

Note that you may wish to change from `List<T>` to `IList<T>` or even a broader interface.

Comment: Of course, this forces you to supply the same information twice: both the type argument for whatever descendant of List<U> that you supply as T, and again as U. So, it would be Parse<List<int>,int>, or Parse<List<string>,string>, etc., which seems redundant.

Comment: But as I read the question, the caller wants to specify a subclass of List<T>

    MYlist<int> data = Parse<Mylist<int>>(whatever)

Comment: Then they'd have to use the first form, and also specify a new() constraint on T so that it can actually be constructed. That's a pretty odd requirement though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I read the question correctly, and you want to return `T` where `T : List<U>` (for some `T` and `U`)...

As an aside - subclassing `List<T>` isn't usually very useful... `List<T>` doesn't provide any useful virtual methods. Subclassing `Collection<T>` provides more flexibility. Of course, you can make your code not care, by simply coding against the `IList<T>` interface, perhaps adding `: new()` so you can create the list itself:

```
public static TList Parse<TList, TItem>(string datadictionary)
    where TList : IList<TItem>, new() {...}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to restrict TIitem in your example?

Comment: @Edoode, sure - just add a second "where" - i.e. "where TItem : class, IFoo"

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this, without specifying a restriction of type `List<u>`

```
 public static List<T> Parse<T>(string datadictionary) ...
```